# Trying to get a view controller to appear after a method has been declared

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview, pushviewcontroller

Here is my code, I don't know what's wrong with it. I am concern about the ImagePickerController method. Is something wrong with it? I declared the property for image view , I just want the ViewController to transition to my EditViewController , but after I have selected the image,  it gets me back to ViewController instead of edit view controller. 
ViewController.h :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <iAd/iAd.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate ,
UINavigationControllerDelegate ,ADBannerViewDelegate>

-(IBAction)GoToEdit:(id)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@property (strong,nonatomic) UIImage *chosenImage;
@property (strong,nonatomic) UIImagePickerController *imagePicker;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)chooseImage:(id)sender {
self.imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
self.imagePicker.delegate = self;
[self.imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
[self presentViewController:self.imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}


-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker    didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:
(NSDictionary *)info{
self.chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
[self.imageView setImage:self.chosenImage];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
EditViewController *editViewController = [[EditViewController alloc]init];
editViewController.chosenImage = self.chosenImage;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:editViewController animated:YES];
}
```

EditViewController.h (Declaring Property for ImageView)

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface EditViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong,nonatomic) UIImage *chosenImage;

@end
```

Comment: Put the editviewcontroller stuff in the completion handler of dismissViewControllerAnimated.

Answer (score 0):

In your imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo replace the last 4 with:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    EditViewController *editViewController = [[EditViewController alloc]init];
    editViewController.chosenImage = self.chosenImage;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:editViewController animated:YES];
}];
```

Comment: Hi Greg , I'm now getting an error "incompatible pointer types assigning to 'UIImageView*' from  'UIImage*'"

Comment: This part of code you shown here looks fine. Can you post code where you use chosenImage on your EditViewController.m file? Do you know on which line you get this error?

Comment: Hi Greg , I fixed the error , but it still isn't opening up EditViewController. I declared chosenImage on EditViewController.h or should I have declared it on EditViewController.m?

Comment: Are you sure you use UINavigationController? If you don't try presentModalViewController instead of pushViewController. Your chosenImage is declared right in .h file.